# How do I create a dependent inner component?

Tags: visualforce-component

I know standard Salesforce has component dependencies on certain components; I want to recreate that functionality. For example if I attempt to use `<apex:commandButton>` outside of a `<apex:form>` wrapper I get the following error:

**`Error: <apex:commandButton> must occur between <apex:form></apex:form> tags`**

The requirement is as follows:

```
<apex:form> 
    <apex:commandbutton/> // required inside apex:form
</apex:form>
```

**I want to be able to create this same dependency** for a custom component. Is this possible and if so how?

For example if I put `<c:innerComponent>` somewhere on the page, I want it to prevent compiling and provide an error that that tag must be within an `<c:outerComponent>` tag

**`Error: <c:innerComponent> must occur between <c:outerComponent></c:outerComponent> tags`**

Meaning if I want to use the `innerComponent` then the `outerComponent` is required

```
<c:outerComponent> 
    <c:innerComponent/> // required inside c:outerComponent
</c:outerComponent>
```

Comment: use `<apex:form>` only in vf page not in component.. so when you add commandbutton in cmp then it will inside vf `apex:form`

Comment: Xtremefaith.. Can you pls add pseudo code, how you are implementing?

Comment: I did already... see references to `<c:innerComponent>` and `<c:outerComponent>`

Comment: I don't mean this to sound facetious as I can't think of a way to solve this but you could rename `innerComponent` to `innerComponent_UseWithinOuterComponent` to help avoid issues

Comment: That's not necessary. We have documented processes to avoid this, I was just hoping to create the same ability in my custom component that Salesforce has  in its standard components. I think this helps with overall consistency

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to that out-of-the-box. What you could try is to add an attribute linked the parent component controller.

You won't have a nice dependency message like the one you mentioned, but you do ensure that only components with the correct controller can call the child component.

Something like this:

```
public class ParentComponentController {
    public ParentComponentController controller { get { return this; } }

    public ParentComponentController() {
        //do your stuff or leave it empty
    }
}
```

Child Component:

```
<apex:component >

    <apex:attribute name="dependency" type="ParentComponentController" required="true" description="securitycheck"/>

</apex:component>
```

Parent Component:

```
<apex:component controller="ParentComponentController">
    <c:dependency="{!controller}" /> 
</apex:component>
```

P.s.: I couldn't save this on the IDE, but if try it on the browser ir works fine.